# How to access a service added to DI container from inside Asp.Net Core's ConfigureServices method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

The code sample below is from Asp.Net Core `ConfigureServices` method in Startup.cs.

I am first registering a singleton service called `AppState`. Subsequent to that, I am configuring OpenIdConnect, and inside the `OnTokenValidated` lambda, I need to access the `AppState` service that I just registered in the DI container up above.

What is the most elegant way of accessing the `AppState` service instance?

I would prefer to not call `services.BuildServiceProvider()` inside the `ConfigureServices` method if at all possible.

```
services.AddSingleton<AppState>();

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADB2CDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
        {
            //How to get access to instance of AppState, 
            //which was added to DI container up above
            AppState appState = //{get from DI somehow}; 
            appState.DoSomething();
        }
    };
});
```

EDIT: Using the answer below, I edited the code like so, but I can confirm that the OnTokenValidated event is not firing, as opposed to the code above in my original question, which does fire:

```
services.AddOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADB2CDefaults.OpenIdScheme)
            .Configure<IServiceScopeFactory>((options, sp) => {
                using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
                {
                    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                    {
                        OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
                        {
                            var appState = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppState>();

                            await appState.Dosomething();         
                        }
                    };
                }
            });
```

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks for your answer...Could you please advise what I might be doing wrong. I have edited my question with the new code, and the OnTokenValidated does not fire.

Answer (score 9):

Use the [`TokenValidatedContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.tokenvalidatedcontext) to get access to the current request service provider and resolve the service

```
services
    .Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADB2CDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options => {
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents {
            OnTokenValidated = async ctx => {
                //Get access to instance of AppState, 
                //which was added to DI container up above
                AppState appState = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices
                    .GetRequiredService<AppState>();
                await appState.DoSomething();

                //...
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: This has helped me get closer to a similar issue, but what I find here is that the OnTokenValidated event seems to only fire if i log into the WebApp from the home page (when using razor) I'm trying to figure out how to get this to fire when the login process is initiated from any protected page or resource.

Answer (score 4):

You can access the DI service from the event context:

```
services.AddSingleton<AppState>();

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADB2CDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
        {
            var appState = (AppState)ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(AppState));
            appState.DoSomething();
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `services.Configure<T>`, adds an `IConfigureOptions<T>` to the service container that calls your action method;
https://github.com/aspnet/Options/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L72

You can define your own implementation of `IConfigureOptions<T>` and inject any service you like.