# What is the proper way to access a service in builder.Services.AddAuthentication?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASMN project that uses an external Identity Server service to authenticate and sign in users. Once authenticated, I need to look up and populate a series of app-specific claims before the user is redirected to the Blazor app. I do this in my server `Program.cs` file in the `OnUserInformationReceived` event that is availble as part of `AddOpenIdConnect`

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";

                    options.ClientId = "bff";
                    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                    options.ResponseType = "code";
                    options.ResponseMode = "query";

                    options.Scope.Clear();
                    options.Scope.Add("openid");
                    options.Scope.Add("profile");
                    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                    options.Scope.Add("email");

                    options.MapInboundClaims = false;
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                    options.SaveTokens = true;

                    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                    {
                        OnUserInformationReceived = async ctx =>
                        {
                            var sub = ctx.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub").Value;

                            using (ServiceProvider serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider())
                            {
                                var userService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<Hermes.Services.User.IUserService>();

                                var claims = await userService.GetUserDetails(sub);

                                var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

                                ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
                            }

                        }
                    };
                });
```

This seems to be working, but I am getting a warning message on `using (ServiceProvider serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider())` that says

> Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in an
> additional copy of singleton services being created. Consider
> alternatives such as dependency injecting services as parameters to
> 'Configure'.

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm doing? I'm using .NET 7 and below is a full copy of my Program.cs file.

```
public partial class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            var CommonConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("CommonConnection");
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<CommonDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(CommonConnectionString);
                options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
            });

            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
            builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

            builder.Services.AddBff().AddServerSideSessions();

            builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<Hermes.Services.User.IUserService, UserService>();

            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "cookie";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
                options.DefaultSignOutScheme = "oidc";
            })
                .AddCookie("cookie", options =>
                {
                    options.Cookie.Name = "__Host-blazor";
                    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
                    options.SlidingExpiration = false;
                })
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";

                    options.ClientId = "bff";
                    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                    options.ResponseType = "code";
                    options.ResponseMode = "query";

                    options.Scope.Clear();
                    options.Scope.Add("openid");
                    options.Scope.Add("profile");
                    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                    options.Scope.Add("email");

                    options.MapInboundClaims = false;
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                    options.SaveTokens = true;

                    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                    {
                        OnUserInformationReceived = async ctx =>
                        {
                            var sub = ctx.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub").Value;

                            using (ServiceProvider serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider())
                            {
                                var userService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<Hermes.Services.User.IUserService>();

                                var claims = await userService.GetUserDetails(sub);

                                var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

                                ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
                            }

                        }
                    };
                });

            var QualityAssuranceConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("QualityAssuranceConnection");
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<QualityAssuranceDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(QualityAssuranceConnectionString);
                options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
            });
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWorkQA, UnitOfWorkQA>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IQualityAssuranceService, QualityAssuranceService>();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseBff();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapBffManagementEndpoints();

            app.MapRazorPages();
            app.MapControllers();
            app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually you can find similar questions on SO. Have you tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61004263/21836370) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62438364/21836370)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access a service added to DI container from inside Asp.Net Core's ConfigureServices method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61003307/how-to-access-a-service-added-to-di-container-from-inside-asp-net-cores-configu)